# How to create an FTP/SFTP user to manage /var/www which is owned by www-data

Tags: 20.04, permissions, apache2, ftp, ownership

I am trying to create an FTP user that can manage the /var/www directory which is owned by www-data.

I have seen a post suggesting this:

```
chown -R newuser:www-data /var/www
```

How do I create a user and allow that user to manage /var/www without changing ownership of that directory?

Comment: Adding `newuser` to the `www-data` group may be what you're looking for ...

Comment: @matigo Thank you. When I do that the user is not able to create any files or directories.

Comment: FYI Apache doesn't need to own the directory, you need to give www-data proper permissions in the subdirs to traverse/recurse.  That'll be dependent on your application.  I have **NUMEROUS** applications running in `myuser:www-data` setups where I own the files and can edit but so can Apache where it *needs* to.  That's a permissions issue that can be resolved easily, Apache doesn't need to own the directory it just needs access to directories and such where it needs ti (based on what your site's application needs are)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not change the owner of the website files, the problem you encountered may occur
Add your editor user to the www-data user group

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data newuser
```

Working with user groups is in line with good practice standards

If you need help with the ftp server setup (directory permissions and restriction), you should specify which ftp server your are running.